# Does the combinatorics proof of Fermat's Little Theorem provide a proof that $n!\mid n^p-n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, solution-verification

> **Question:** In view of the fact that there are $n!$ $n-$permutations of
> $n$ colors, does the combinatorics proof of Fermat's Little Theorem
> provide a proof that $n!\mid n^p-n$?

My attempt:-

**Combinatorics proof of Fermat's Little theorem(statement:-If $p$ is a prime and $n$ is a positive integer. Then, $p \mid n^p-n.$) :-**
Suppose that we wish to form strings of $p$ colored beads each, and that we have on hand enough beads to permit unlimited use of each of $n$ colors. By
the general combinatorics principle, there are $n^p$ different strings, since
each bead may be chosen in exactly $n$ ways and since there are $p$
choices for each string. Of the $n^p$ possibilities, exactly $n$ strings have beads of only one color. We can alter any string of beads by removing a bead from the top end and placing it on the bottom end; this alteration produces a different string of beads without changing the resulting bracelet.
Let $k$ be the least number of times this alteration may be repeated before the original color scheme of the string is reproduced. Certainly $k> 1$, since we have set aside all mono color strings. Note that after $2k$ steps the bracelet's original color scheme will again be reproduced; and, similarly, after $3k$ steps, $4k$ steps, and so on. By Euclid's division lemma, there exist $h$ and $r$ such that
$$p=hk+r ,(0 \leq r<k).$$ Since the color scheme is reproduced after $hk$ steps and is also reproduced after $p$ steps (because after $p$ steps all the beads are back in their original positions), it takes exactly $r$ steps after the $hk$th step to get a reproduction of the color scheme. Since $r<k$ and $k$ is the least positive number of steps required to obtain a reproduction, we see that $r$ must be $0$. Hence $p= hk$, and so $k= p$, since $k > 1$ and $p$ is a prime. Consequently the $n^p-n$ strings fall naturally into groups of $p$ strings each, and it is clear that each group gives rise to a separate bracelet. Thus the number of bracelets $N$ multiplied by $p$ gives the number of strings that are not monocolor, namely $n^p-n$.

Hence $pN=n^p-n$; that is, $p \mid n^p-n$.

I am not able to see any factor $n!$ in the proof. May I get help?

Comment: $n!$ does not always divide $n^p-n$ -- take $n=4$ and $p=3$, for example.

Comment: Where does the proof comes false, when $p$ turn to $n!$?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: @Unknownx If you replace $p$ with $n!$, then it fails here: "Hence $p= hk$, and so $k= p$, since $k > 1$ and **$p$ is a prime.**" [emphasis mine] There are lots of nontrivial divisors of $n!$, and when $k$ is one of these, then you wouldn't be able to guarantee that there are $n!$ distinct strings in each group.

Comment: This thing I noted@BriangMoehring Does the combinatorics proof of Fermat's Little Theorem provide a proof that $n!∣n^p−n$
? What is the meaning of this question? Are they asking "Where does the proof comes false, when $p$ turn to $n!?$" ?

Comment: I think this problem wants you to use the "permutation of colors" instead of "rotation" in the proof. And the problem comes from the fact that it is possible that the colors are the same w.r.t two different permutations of colors (while the key point of the combinatorial proof is that among the p rotations you cannot have two identical color assignments). For example, if only two colors are used, then the permutation of the other colors does not change the results at all.

Comment: I did not find a pair $(n,p)$ yet with $n\ge 8 $ integer and $p$ prime such that $n!|n^p-n$ holds. There are not only a few exceptions , it seems that $n!|n^p-n$ very rarely holds. So how on earth should there be a combinatorical proof for it ? Is there a restricttion to $n$ , say $n\le 7$ ?